# How to create global layout component in React native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, layout, global

I use React router flux in my project and I need to global view for my app
so I created component called `layout` but this did not answer.
My code:

---layout component

```
 render() {
        return (
<View style={[styles.container,styles.justify_center,styles.align_items_center]}>

</View>
        );
    }
```

---login component

```
render() {
        return (
 <layout>
<Text>Test</Text>
</layout>
        );
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any chance to use a component as a global ActivityIndicator on React-Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41554340/is-there-any-chance-to-use-a-component-as-a-global-activityindicator-on-react-na)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `this.props.children` in a component to include all the children included in the invokation of this component.

Just update your layout component as shown bellow :

```
render() {
  return (
    <View style={[styles.container,styles.justify_center,styles.align_items_center]}>
      {this.props.children}
    </View>
  );
}
```